# Reducing disk usage on Lotus Sametime

Tags: performance, anti-virus, lotus-sametime

My Lotus Sametime (8.5.2) freezes every few seconds, while reading/writing to disk.
Process Explorer show heavy disk I/O.

I suspect sametime writes logs and the antivirus locks the file while it's being written, causing the freeze. I can't disable the AV, and don't really want to give up chat logs as they are useful from time to time.

Any ideas?

Comment: phone their support for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the AV you could exclude just the sametime directories from realtime scanning.